# cannot create flutter project in vscode (new one )

Tags: flutter

every time I create a new flutter project  in vs code i had this error

---

[flutter_application_correct] flutter create --template app --overwrite .
'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
exit code 1

---

What is the solution then?

Comment: are you tryin to create it via cmd line? please tell what you did to create the project

Answer (score 0):

apparently you don't have flutter installed in your development environment, or you have a problem with your sdk, to solve it I recommend you check the official flutter documentation.

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install

If this doesn't work for you, you could try the 'flutter doctor' command.